# このサイトの疑問点・改善点をメタで教えてください！

Tags: サポート

> <sup>「メタって何？」と思った方は、[ヘルプセンターの記事](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)もご覧ください。</sup>

先日ユーザーからメールで非常にいい改善点のまとめを頂きました。

「メタで投稿するのはどうですか？」と聞いたら、「信用度5点以上がないので投稿できませんでした。」と答えてくれました。

当サイトを改善するモチベーションがあれば、メールより、メタで投稿した方がコミュニティ全体で参加・討議ができます。そこで、メタ投稿の信用度制限を外すことにしました。

次のようなことを考えたことはありませんか？

- 私の質問がマイナス投票されたのはなぜですか？
- ○○ページに英語があるのはどうして？
- これはどういう機能？説明がわかりにくい！
- どうすれば○○できますか？
- ○○すればもっといいサイトになるのに！

当コミュニティは皆様のおかげでここまで成長できました。改善点等があればぜひメタに投稿してください。

Comment: ヘルプセンターの「メタへの参加」のページで、まだ「信用度が 5 点必要」と書かれています。

Comment: @9walk リンクを教えていただけますか？

Comment: ヘルプセンター＞権限＞メタへの参加 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta 「そこに投稿するのに信用度が 5 点必要なのはなぜですか?」

Comment: @9walk 更新しました：http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta