# スタック・オーバーフローMetaへの質問に必要な信用度が5のままになっている

Tags: サポート, 完了, メタ

[このサイトの疑問点・改善点をメタで教えてください！](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1856) でメタ投稿に必要な信用度が1点に引き下げられたと思うのですが、新規ユーザーで試したところメタ投稿ができませんでした。

- 新規ユーザーを作成する（信用度1）
- 「質問する」ボタンを押す
- 以下の画面が表示される

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 月曜日に開発者と相談します。大変申し訳ありませんでした！

Comment: @jmac 解決しそうでしょうか？だいぶ時間がかかるようなら、[権限](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)や[ヘルプセンター](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)の記述を元に戻したほうがいいかもしれません。

Comment: @unarist 再現させられていますが、まだ解決はできていないです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

解決しました。信用度レベルを1点以上をさせるには、3つの設定があるらしいです。最初に2つしか変更していなかったため、5点以上のままになってしまいました。

3つを設定した上、信用度１のアカウントでも投稿できると確認しました。